# Что значит "пуся"?

Tags: перевод

Я не смог найти ответ в интернете. И когда можно употреблять это слово?

Comment: by the way, "я не *смог* (perfect) and "*в* интернете"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be different things.

- A transliteration of English word "pussy", when referring to Pussy Riot for instance.
- A contraction of "лапуся", which in turn is a deminutive of "лапа". It means an animal's leg but also used very often to call babies.
- It also can be a deminutive of an animal name Пушок.

I think the second meaning the most widespread.

Comment: I should have added it was said in an affectionate way. Makes sense that it's a contraction. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Мне уже под 50, а слышал я это еще в детстве, а потому смею всех уверить, что никакой связи с "Пусси Р." здесь нет. Попробуйте в любимом поисковике `муси-пуси` или `пуси-муси`, поразглядывайте картинки, употребления, и пр., но с учетом того, что это очень [старый оборот речи](http://russian_argo.academic.ru/6860/%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8), который сегодня, возможно, играет иными красками и созвучиями.

Ну а сокращенно это превращалось в звательное пуся. А кошек называли Муся ))

I'm near 50 years old native Russian speaker, so I can assure you that there is no link with "P u s s y R." at any rate ))

I heard it in childhood as [`пуси-муси, муси-пуси`](http://russian_argo.academic.ru/6860/%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8).

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible meanings - a diminutive form of girl name like Полина, Пелагея:

> **Пуся**: ПЕЛАГЕЯ, ПОЛИНА; [Указатель производных (уменьшительных) имен](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/petr/imsm/)

This name is not modern, [Russian National Corpus](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%F3%F1%FF) has entry dated 1915:

> Числа 16-го **Пуся** с Сашей едут в Смоленск, по-видимому, до середины августа, затем Саша поступит в Павловское училище на четыре месяца, к Рождеству будет офицером. [Н. Н. Пунин. Письма А. Е. Аренс (1915)]

Also, this can be a diminutive for pet name, that starts from letter П (like Пушок from @Anixx example), or has a syllable ПУ (лапа-лапуся-пуся).

Of course, such short word can be reinvented (for instance, derived from *пупсик*, etc.), rethinked as borrowed from English "pussy" and so on, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is close to such English words as "Bae" (baby) and "cutie". You can use it addressing your wife/girlfriend, your child or pet.

Answer (score 0):

I think (and I met it online several times) that the word is a derogatory term for anyone taking part/supporting Pussy Riot. - at least that is the most recent meaning of the word.

However, the word can also mean "something/somebody nice and fluffy".

Answer (score 0):

**Пуся**, также уменьшительно-ласкательное **пусечка** - обращение к детям или к любимому человеку. Происходит от слова "ути-пути" - это говорят ребёнку, который ещё в детской кроватке, обычно ему дают игрушку со словами "ути-пути", чтобы ребёнок засмеялся и перестал плакать. Когда он перестаёт плакать, говорят "ах ты моя пусечка (или **пуся**)". Буквально обозначает то же самое, что и лапа или **лапочка** - то же самое, что и **прелесть**.